# php SoapClient fails when passed a wsdl with relative path schemas

Tags: php, import, wsdl, external, soap-client

I have the following issue:

The instantiation of my SoapClient object fails when I pass it a wsdl that imports a schema using relative paths. (I believe this is the case anyway, based on my research)

My code is as follows:

```
$wsdl = 'http://myproxy/webservice?wsdl';
$options = array( /* options */ );
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
```

The schema import part of the wsdl:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <import namespace="http://myprovider/namespace1/namespace1" schemaLocation="schema1.xsd"/>
  <import namespace="http://myprovider/namespace1/namespace2" schemaLocation="schema2.xsd"/>
  <import namespace="http://myprovider/namespace1/namespace3" schemaLocation="schema3.xsd"/>
</schema>
```

The Error that I get:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://myproxy/webservice?wsdl' : Extra content at the end of the document
```

Research led me to articles such as this:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-484

From what I can tell, it seems I have two options:

- Get my provider to change the schema paths to absolute
- Get my provider to give me a copy of the schema so I can host on my server where the `SoapClient` is being called from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as I had suspected.

The relative path to the schema means that the SoapClient when parsing the wsdl, will try to access the schema files using the proxy as reference, like so:

```
http://myproxy/schema1.xsd
```

Since I do not have the xsd files, this will cause the SoapClient to throw an error.

The solution to this problem then is to eliminate the proxy, so that relative paths to external resources are not affected. The sollution can be found here:

[Extending php SoapClient for siteminder authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212983/extending-php-soapclient-for-siteminder-authentication)

Comment: Any other solutions for this bug ? If we must use the proxy what should I do?